# PowerShell can't find user in AD when trying to add group membership

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to perform a very simple task in PowerShell - adding a member to a group, but for some reason getting the error below.

```
$userDN = $(Get-ADUser FirstName.LastName).DistinguishedName
Write-Host $userDN

Add-ADGroupMember $userDN '2Citrix Users'
```

I can see that the user definitely exists in the domain, as does the group, yet I still see this error:

> Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'CN=FirstName 
>   LastName,OU=Users,OU=BRI,OU=AU,OU=ORGANISATION,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com' under: 
>   'DC=DOMAIN,DC=com'.
>   At line:4 char:1
>   + Add-ADGroupMember $userDN '2Citrix Users'
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=FirstName Las...MAIN,DC=com:ADGroup) [Ad 
>      d-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADId 
>      entityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember

How is this possible? Why can PS find the user with `Get-ADUser` but not with `Add-ADGroupMember`?

The only thing I can think of is that I recently re-enabled the account from a disabled state. Does this need some time to take effect before I can add group membership via PowerShell?

Note that **I am able to add the group membership without any issue in the AD UI**.

Comment: Change order of $userDN and '2Citrix Users' and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Can we see a little more of the surrounding lines of the script?

Comment: When you call `Add-ADGroupMember`, you place group first, users next. It otherwise tries to find a group object named "FirstName LastName", and fails since the object is a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to ALWAYS, espacially in scripts, use the parameter names. This way the order of the parameters does not matter.

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Members $userDN -Identity '2Citrix Users'
```